# can't query upstart service status from cron job

Tags: ubuntu, cron, upstart

I'm running Ubuntu 14 and I added the following line to my crontab:

```
*/1 * * * * : testing; /usr/sbin/service my-service status > ~/status 2>&1
```

After the next minute rolls around, I see this in ~/status:

```
my-service: unrecognized service
```

If I run this from the terminal, it does recognize the service:

```
~$ /usr/sbin/service my-service status
my-service stop/waiting
```

I'm wondering what could be responsible for my service being unrecognized in the cron job's environment but not in my environment when I ssh to the server?

Answer (score 6):

I found that this works:

```
*/1 * * * * : testing; /sbin/initctl status my-service > ~/status 2>&1
```

`/usr/sbin/service` works with SystemV jobs (e.g. those in /etc/init.d), and under Ubuntu it also sees Upstart jobs (e.g. those in /etc/init). `/sbin/initctl` works directly with Upstart jobs. So my guess is that the mechanism that allows `/usr/sbin/service` to see Upstart jobs isn't working for some reason in the environment my cron job runs in, but I'm not sure how to explore that further.

Comment: I'm not accepting my own answer here since it's really just a workaround with a guess as to what was happening.

Comment: Additional details: in the cron environment, /sbin is not include in PATH.  When I execute `PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/sbin service`, my services are recognized.